# Color preview is not shown in sidebar Android Studio IDE

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

The color preview doesn't appear in the sidebar as normally
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

I have found that disabling Power Save Mode solved it.

File-> Power Save Mode

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, modifica tu pregunta, recuerda que el idioma oficial del sitio es el español.